# Facing a very weird problem with citation

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, apacite, multiple-citations

```
\documentclass[11pt,nonatbib]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\begin{document}

    
     A number of studies \citep[e.g.,][]{zhou2008impacts, kouvelis2012financing, seifert2013review, lee2018trade, ning2019commitment} confirm that trade credit induces retailer to over-order.
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        
    \item  \cite{lee1997bullwhip} When I comment this line. The output is different. Ideally as far as I know only last name should be included in citation.
                
        \item \cite{lee2018trade}
        
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{MWE}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the bibliography file content

```
@article{zhou2008impacts,
    title={Impacts of financial collaboration in a three-party supply chain},
    author={Zhou, J and Groenevelt, H},
    journal={Working Paper},
    year={2008},
    publisher={The Simon School, University of Rochester}
}
@article{kouvelis2012financing,
    title={Financing the newsvendor: supplier vs. bank, and the structure of optimal trade credit contracts},
    author={Kouvelis, Panos and Zhao, Wenhui},
    journal={Operations Research},
    volume={60},
    number={3},
    pages={566--580},
    year={2012},
    publisher={INFORMS}
}

@article{seifert2013review,
    title={A review of trade credit literature: Opportunities for research in operations},
    author={Seifert, Daniel and Seifert, Ralf W and Protopappa-Sieke, Margarita},
    journal={European Journal of Operational Research},
    volume={231},
    number={2},
    pages={245--256},
    year={2013},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{lee2018trade,
    title={Trade credit financing under competition and its impact on firm performance in supply chains},
    author={Lee, Hsiao-Hui and Zhou, Jianer and Wang, Jingqi},
    journal={Manufacturing \& Service Operations Management},
    volume={20},
    number={1},
    pages={36--52},
    year={2018},
    publisher={INFORMS}
}

@article{lee1997bullwhip,
    title={The bullwhip effect in supply chains},
    author={Lee, Hau L and Padmanabhan, Venkata and Whang, Seungjin},
    journal={Sloan management review},
    volume={38},
    pages={93--102},
    year={1997}
}

@article{ning2019commitment,
    title={Commitment Role of Trade Credit in a Supply Chain With Buyer Competition},
    author={Ning, Jie},
    journal={Available at SSRN 3474543},
    year={2019}
}
```

[image: The first image is without commenting the first item.]

[image: The second image is after commenting the first item.]
The first image is without commenting the first item.The second image is after commenting the first item.

Comment: There are two authors with surname “Lee” and the style disambiguates by adding name initials.

Comment: By the way, `biblatex` with `style=apa` does exactly the same, so I guess it is an APA style requirement.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

See the [relevant page on the APA website](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/citing-authors-same-surname)

[image]

In your case, if you omit `\cite{lee1997bullwhip}` only one first author with surname “Lee” is cited and so no initials are added. With that citation, to the contrary, the rule about adding initials is enforced.

I checked and the same happens with `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: Yes @egreg...you are right. This is the requirement to distinguish the authors having the same last name. Thanks for sharing the details.